# Problems with some visual residue when doing transitional flip between UIViews (video inside)

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, calayer, transition

So I'm transitioning between two views here by replacing one of the views with the other, but I'm having some problems with some visual residue.

Both views have rounded corners set, and when I do the flip animation there's this rectangular shadow that appears on top of both views. There must be some way of getting rid of this?

Here's my transition code. Transition view is a background view with a clear colored background. Tried adding the second button on top of the first and transitioning that way as well, but that also gave me the same problem.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:transitionView
                  duration:4.7
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                animations:^(void){
                    [clockButton removeFromSuperview];
                    [transitionView addSubview:motorButton];
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                }];
```

Added a YouTube video that shows the problem. Slowed down the transition from the first to the second button so that it's easier to see what is going on.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TemHSL0dfJI

Comment: The funny thing here is that if I use a transparent PNG - instead of programming the rounded corners - then I don't get that shadow on top at all.